# std::ofstream and system touch

Tags: c++, linux

Profiling one of my C++ programs I just discovered that calling std::ofstream(), when creating a bunch of files, takes much less time than using the system "touch".

So now I was wondering what OS function the std::ofstream is mapped to, on Linux.

Do you know what std::ofstream() calls to create a file?

Thanks

Comment: Are you issuing the `system "touch"` from the command-line or from within the program as function call `system("touch ...");` ?

Comment: How do you compare the performance of C++ function (std::ofstream constructor) vs that of an executable (/bin/touch)?

Comment: yes, I use system() or, better: sprintf(temp, "touch %s", qPrintable(fileName) ). But from the answers I now understood why I got such an overhead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are doing `system("touch filename");` this is misleading and slow (and a security risk, and, and ...). It doesn't call the system as such, but spawns a shell, then runs the program (touch in this case) in it.
Opening a stream will use some kind of actual system call that can directly access the filesystem. Possibly http://linux.die.net/man/2/open on Linux.
Try running `strace touch` in a terminal to find out what system calls it is making. You could probably do the same with a simple c++ program you create just opening a file. Or if you are using an open source implementation (gcc) you can check the source.

Comment: a bit off topic, but this might help someone else like me. I wanted to create a file from within a mac application. system("touch filename") did the job, except it created on the disk root. How come? I thought it would prefer the relative path and touch a file in the same path... thks!

Comment: @StinkyCat You're somewhat missing the point, which is that **`system()` is evil, don't use it!** But it just so happens I was trying to test something with process return values today, and had a similar issue! On some platforms it could find a local program, on some it couldn't. `system` starts up a new shell, and I guess there is nothing to say that the new shell will start in the same directory as the program is running in, although it seems to on Linux. Anyway, the posix standard says it will be ["executed in an implementation-defined manner"](http://goo.gl/65q46).

Comment: yes i got it from reading your answer :) But I was just making a small test, and it struck me as a big question to let it go. Yet you made it clear, thank you!

Comment: Actually, I just tested `system("pwd")` on Linux, Solaris and AIX, and they all gave me the same directory I started in (well, Solaris expanded out a soft link). So in short, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

You should also consider the execution overhead of `touch` as a binary. I believe the performance increase is mostly due to having a persistent binary in the memory when measuring `ofstream`.

Comment: Good point, I believe an operating system process will be created when executing touch.

Answer (score 1):

Think about `system()`.  It is going to fork/exec a shell which is going to load the touch binary, shared libs, etc., from disk, execute it, clean up the process and return.

If you are just using touch to create non-existing files then it mostly it is equivalent to std::ofstream.open() which is going to execute some function calls and ultimately resolve to the system call `open()` and eventually `close()`.  A lot faster.  However, if you are really emulating the capabilities of `touch` then it is more complicated.  E.G. if the file already exists it will only change the timestamps, etc., and more is involved.

Regardless of your actual usage coding it in C++ is going to be faster than running an external program via `system()`.